# Importing Maki Icons to QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapbox

Does anyone know how to import [Maki Icons](http://mapbox.com/maki/) to QGIS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Download and unarchive to a destination to which you have read rights, then add the path to the individual SVG symbols...

`path-to-mapbox-maki-download\src\nounproject`

to the SVG paths dialog in QGIS Rendering preferences by clicking **Add**:

[image]

After doing this, I had to restart QGIS (1.8.0 on Mac, here) for the symbols to become automatically available in the old and new symbology dialogs and in Print Composer for placed images.

[image]

Comment: now source svg is only one with all the icons in it... how to split them in multiple files?

Comment: As an update to future readers, as of QGIS 2.4, the SVG Paths settings box is under `Options -> System`, not Rendering.

Answer (score 6):

With QGIS 3 (and 2), the Maki icons can conveniently be imported using the *Resource Sharing* plugin. It is available in the QGIS plugin repository, so it is very easy to install it using the QGIS *Plugin Manager*.
The Maki icons are in a collection on the QGIS Resources repository, so you only need to:

1. Open the *Resource Sharing* plugin
2. Go to Settings
3. Press *Reload Repositories*
4. Go to *All*
5. Find **Mapbox's Maki Icons**, and select it (by clicking)
6. Click on *Install*

The Maki icons (SVGs) should now have been downloaded and installed in your local file system, and your SVG path should have been updated to include them.
So to use an icon from this collection for *Single symbol* rendering,
you only need to:

1. Select **Simple marker** under **Marker**
2. Choose `SVG marker` for **Symbol layer type**. *SVG Groups* will open near the bottom
3. Scroll down a bit there, and you will find *Resource Sharing-> Mapbox's Maki icons.
4. Click on that entry, and only the Maki icons will be displayed in the *SVG image* area

   [image: Maki icons - QGIS Symbology]
5. Choose your favorite icon

Answer (score 4):

To import the icons in QGIS for Windows download and extract them to the following folder

C:\Program Files(x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\svg\mapbox_maki

*or equivalent folder where QGIS is installed.

[image]

In the **Layer Properties** (add a point layer in first)
Click 'Add' bottom left (not the import on the right)
Select the Symbol Marker type to .svg
locate the extracted folder location and click on an .svg icon and give it a name, you will have to repeat this step many times as there is no bulk load option currently.
you can also change point size here or at another time.

That will import all the Mapbox Maki svg files into QGIS.

[image]

Comment: A note to OSGeo4W users: the default svg folder will get clobbered when you upgrade.  This issue can be avoided with dakcarto's answer.

Comment: Users can set the mapbox_maki folder in C:\Program Files(x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\svg to be read only and not be deleted in Windows 7 using Deny to System under security settings/permissions.