# Importing SVG symbols into QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, svg

I've downloaded the SVG icon pack from https://www.mapbox.com/maki/

Using the Import from URL has never worked for me, so how do I import these symbols into QGIS?

As far as I can tell I need an .XML defining each symbol.

Comment: I had this issue moving from QGIS 2.12 to 2.16 (fresh install on new computer).
My symbols are on remote file system, so I thought QGIS resource sharing can be helpful. But wasn't able to create a repository or even load a clone of your dummy repository. I even try to use it from my document folder so simplify the path (en avoid accent): C:\Users\myfolder\QGIS-style-repo-dummy-master But I still get this error: Unable to add repository: Metadata file does not exist in the repository EDIT:
System: windows 7 SP1 (64 bits)
QGIS: 2.16.0
QGIS Resource Sharing: 0.5.1 Issue published on github too

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/349965 contains a step by step recipe for installing the "Maki" SVG symbols using the QGIS Resource Sharing plugin (QGIS 3).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Another way is to point your SVG adding their path in:

`Settings->Options->System->SVG Path`

In this way you'll find your SVG symbols as group in QGIS styler (Layer Properties->Style....)

Comment: I've added the path to QGIS however when I go (Layer Properties > Style Manager > Marker Symbols) Nothing new shows up...

Comment: I tried re-install and deleting reg keys for QGIS still no luck, I only have 14 marker symbols to choose from...

Answer (score 24):

I hope this is what you are searching for :

1. Make sure you have right path to [your svg directory](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/137886/9857).
2. go to layer properties>style, click **simple marker** (below **Marker**), then on symbol layer tab change it to svg marker
   (on pic)

[image]
[image]

Comment: How incredibly non-intuitive.

Answer (score 9):

The most convenient way right now to share SVG in QGIS is to use QGIS Resource Sharing plugin (you can install it from QGIS Plugin Manager). Maki icons are shipped into one of the approved repositories that you can use them right away. Read more about this plugin here http://www.akbargumbira.com/qgis_resources_sharing/

Comment: Documentation of the QGIS Resource Sharing plugin has been moved to http://qgis-contribution.github.io/QGIS-ResourceSharing,

Answer (score 9):

[Checked **QGIS 2.14 / 2.18**]

Yet another way is to create a new folder under  `C:/Users/your_name/.qgis2` and name it `svg`. This new `C:/Users/your_name/.qgis2/svg` is automatically recognized by QGIS as the path to pre-defined `User Symbols` Group.

Then just copy the downloaded icons into it. The top-level folder (just below `svg`) will become the subgroup name.

So, `C:/Users/your_name/.qgis2/svg/MAKI` will be:

[image]

---

(Update for **QGIS 3.0**)

QGIS 3.0 does not use `.qgis2` folder anymore, so the location has to be checked by opening `Settings | User Profiles | Open Active Profile Folder`.

Create `svg` folder in this location. Then again, QGIS will recognize it as the User's `svg` folder.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just copy the folder with SVG icons to your QGIS SVG folder. On Windows it C:\OSGeo4W64_2.8.1\apps\qgis\svg depending on your installation path. Restart QGIS if open when copying.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Kazuhito, that worked for me. In MacOS, the path for QGIS 3 is
/Users/*user_name*/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/svg

From there you can modify the SVG files without opening the program, though QGIS does seem to update these files without restarting.