# Creating symbol for "Great Wall of China" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, china

I wanted to create a symbol like this (see screenshots below(first and second: white circle)), the shape of these symbols are different, some of them are a straight line, some of them are curved. How do I do it?

Screenshot 1

[image]

Screenshot 2 (See white circle)

[image]

**How can I reduce the space between line and rectangle?**

[image]

Comment: I posted a similar question before. [JGH](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84870/jgh) provided a nice [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/241825/84455) using SVG symbol. It may applicable to your case, too.

Comment: @Kazuhito btw: if its "single symbol", how to style the line with two Marker lines? simply by clicking "+" or use "rule based" ? thx again

Comment: If the line is a mix of two markers, yes, I would probably click "+" to add second marker and set `offset` to make sure these markers do not hide each other.

Comment: @Kazuhito yes, I've figured it out. but in the "answer" said: "Each Marker line is made of a Simple Marker, the half-circle."--->"half-circle": instead of half circle, I need a half rectangle, i found only full not half...:( plz help..

Comment: I see your point. The linked answer by JGH had started from a half-circle, so it required another (180-rotated) marker. If you have full cycle rectangle, you do not need second marker.

Comment: @Kazuhito thanks! the last question plz: I've updated my question, see plz the last screenshot, how can I connect the line with rectangles? sorry, i found it! thank you so much!!!

Comment: Maybe this SVG-less solution could help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241802/drawing-wavy-wiggly-lines-in-qgis/354873#354873

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just in case you need a "gear-like" SVG symbol:

```
<svg width="5.0" height="2.5" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 5.0 2.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d="m0 1.25v1.24h2.48v-2.48h2.48v1.25" fill="none" stroke="param(outline)" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 0.2"/>
</svg>
```

I am not good at drawing. Modify as required.

Credit should go to [JGH](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84870/jgh) for all the ideas and detailed steps provided in the answer to  [Drawing wavy, wiggly lines in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/241825/84455).

One additional from me is: Please keep the `marker interval` and `size` <s>`width`</s> equal. (Click on the `Marker line` as seen on the picture below to find `interval`. In this example `size` <s>`width`</s> and `interval` are both 4.0 mm.)

[image]

---

*Further notes*

- SVG path has to be set correctly (e.g. [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/239156/84455)).
- SVG symbol `outline width` might have been preset to `No outline` or `0 (automatic)` depending on previous SVG setting, which makes it invisible. Set it to 0.2 mm or any other numbers.

Comment: My apologies @ndr I have mixed up `size` and `width` probably looking at somewhere else. That part should read "`size` and `marker interval` are the same".

Comment: @ndr Just one possibility; do you see the `Outline width` in the SVG marker settings? If it is set to `No outline` the marker does not show up.

Comment: @ndr As far as I see from your third image (Layer Properties), you are doing the same as myself. Perhaps you can post your SVG file (as I have done so in my answer) so that I can test it?

Comment: I see. Sorry I misunderstood @ndr. Only difference I now see is I put SVG files in my `.qgis2/svg` folder. My procedure is described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/239156/84455). Not sure it works for you, though.

Comment: hey, thank you for your help. I found the problem: 1) wrong svg path 2) i have to set the 'outline width' to 0.2 or something, it was 0 (automatic) (under "SVG marker"). now is working,well at least i saw the symbol on my map. thanks a million! you are the best! thank you !

Comment: Thanks @ndr I am glad it worked out. I will edit some text to reflect additional information we found for future readers.