# Specialized symbology packages for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology

I would like to display a map of different biotopes in QGIS. In ArcMap, I can use predefined symbology for various topics by searching for it; e.g. for nature conservation issues.

Is there anything like that in QGIS, or are there predefined symbology packages that I could download?

Comment: While there are predefined symbologies, they don't necessarily fit what you're searching for. On the other hand you easily may create your own symbology, e.g. following guidelines/symbologies used by local authorities, and save those as `.qml` or `.xml`.

Comment: See this link: https://anitagraser.com/2016/10/23/more-icons-symbols-for-qgis/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong, but are you perhaps interested in Animal symbols?

There is a github repo - [QGISsvgAnimals](https://github.com/kazuhito84455/QGISsvgAnimals) - of SVG symbols of animals (posted under the `Unlicense`).

Example:

[image]

To install SVG icons, this thread [Importing SVG symbols into QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137855/importing-svg-symbols-into-qgis/239156#239156) may help.

*(Disclaimer - I started the above github... forgotten the password... it's been left there quite a while......)*