# QGis 3 plugin for more symbols

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, symbology

I'm looking for a plugin to get more symbols (trees, airport, trainstation...).I want to use it to show my travelling route. So that I can set a point and change the symbology to a pictogram of an airport.  Is there a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [QGIS Resource Sharing](https://qgis-contribution.github.io/QGIS-ResourceSharing/) pluggin.

Alternatively you could create (using some vector graphic software like inkscape or illustrator) or download SVG symbol and [use them in QGIS symbology](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137855/importing-svg-symbols-into-qgis)